# What can cause hover font to render in different color to css?

Tags: html, css, browser

I have a :hover selector for a link, and have the color property set, pretty standard stuff:

```
a.someclass:hover {
   color: #00b49d;
}
```

But for some reason, on hover, it actually renders a slightly different color - checked with a color picker utility, which gives a different result to the defined style (which has also been verified in the web inspector).

Doesn't happen in all browsers - for example it renders correctly in Chrome Ubuntu, but not in Chrome OSX.

I'm wondering what sorts of things can cause this? I've tried using the non-standard font smoothing properties, to turn off antialiasing (just to check) and it's still rendering in a different color. Any ideas?

Comment: One thing is to check if you don't have other styles that overrides your class, such as Opacity. Also to make sure your colors are true, you need to check the color profile you use on your computer and screen settings (Color LCD / Adobe RGB 1998, etc...) because every screen have different [color tongues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CIExy1931_sRGB_gamut_D65.png) and the color you might be using would be outside your color tongue range.

Comment: Using the Chrome Devtools, inspect the element. (You can right click on it on the DOM tree to force it to be on a :hover state). On the right pane, go to the `computed` tab. Look for color and see what rules are being applied to it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I haven't seen any obvious evidence of colors being changed when looking at the dev tools, or opacity or anything. It might be the color-tongue thing, not sure....